# Generate long time facebook user access token for Fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can generate 60 min valid user token via Graph API Explore, but for extending it

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

we need to have app_ID and APP_secret. Is APP_ID my userID and APP_Secret my password ?

Do I need to have a facebook application for extending user access token to manage my facebook fan page (I dont have any FB application).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a FB application (it's actually quite quick to [set up](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)). Or to just play around, try the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Comment: and how can I give post permission to FB App to write in Fan page ?

Comment: for that you'll need the [manage_pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/page-permissions/) permission. btw, feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem.